# Can't resolve method .getFilter()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, searchview

I can't seem to find what is the issue with my Adapter that I can't use .getFilter() method on OnQueryTextChange. I called my adapter called mAdapter and there's no method for .getFilter(). I believe that there is some issue with my Adapter but I have spent quite awhile to figure it out.

Here is my Adapter

```
    package Adapters;

import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.MuaView;
import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.R;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MuaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MuaAdapter.MuaViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<MuaView> mMuaView;
    private List<MuaView> mMuaViewFull;

    public static class MuaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageButton mImageButton;
        public TextView mTextView1;

        public MuaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mua_imageButton);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mua_title);
        }
    }

    public MuaAdapter(List<MuaView> muaView) {
        this.mMuaView = muaView;
        mMuaViewFull = new ArrayList<>(muaView);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MuaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mua_view, parent, false);
        MuaViewHolder mvh = new MuaViewHolder(v);
        return mvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MuaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MuaView currentView = mMuaView.get(position);

        holder.mImageButton.setImageResource(currentView.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentView.getText1());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMuaView.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return MuaFilter;
    }

    private Filter MuaFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<MuaView> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mMuaViewFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (MuaView item : mMuaViewFull) {
                    if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mMuaView.clear();
            mMuaView.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}
```

Here is my Activity

```
    package android.com.example.weddingappfinale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Adapters.MuaAdapter;

public class MuaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mua_list);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Make Up Artists");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ArrayList<MuaView> muaView = new ArrayList<>();
        muaView.add(new MuaView(R.drawable.mua_image, "Make Up Artist Pte Ltd"));
        muaView.add(new MuaView(R.drawable.mua_image, "Aake Up Artist Pte Ltd"));
        muaView.add(new MuaView(R.drawable.mua_image, "Lake Up Artist 3Pte Ltd"));
        muaView.add(new MuaView(R.drawable.mua_image, "f Up Artist Pte Ltd"));

        // ArrayList

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new MuaAdapter(muaView);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            });
        return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
```

replace

```
private MuaAdapter mAdapter;
```

The problem was that the getFilter method is only present in the MuaAdapter class, and the RecyclerView.Adapte does not know anything about getFilter

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Yes. This is right. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Override` annotation tells the compiler you're want to override the `getFilter` method in `RecyclerView.Adapter` - but there is no such method. Remove the annotation.

```
// @Override <-- REMOVE THIS
public Filter getFilter() {
    return MuaFilter;
}
```

You also need to change the member variable declaration in your activity.

```
private MuaAdapter mAdapter;
```